# Include text changes in current Undo group in RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a UWP application and I'm using a [`RichEditBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox) control, and I'm having some issues with the undo feature.

I know I can use the `BeginUndoGroup` method from the [`ITextDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument) object exposed by the `RichEditBox` to create an undo group I can use while editing my text, so the user will undo all those changes together (when I call `EndUndoGroup` too).

The issue for me is that I have some autocomplete functionality in my app, and I don't know how to make it so that the characters/changes I add for the autocomplete are included in the previous undo group.

> For example, say you enter the 'h' character, I detect that from the `TextChanged` event (or another event from the `RichEditBox` and I add "ello" to the text, so you end up with "hello", and then color the whole word in green.
>
> If I use the `BeginUndoGroup` method, I can undo both the added "ello" and the green color, but the user will still end up with the 'h' character being there.
>
> Or, if for example I color each new character in a random color, I have no idea how to make it so that the undo feature will undo both my color change and the previous character entered by the user.

Is there any way to get around this (ie. to include some changes in the current/previous undo group), or do I just have to come up with some dirty hack like calling the `Undo` method twice when the user wants to undo a change, hoping he won't notice the text flickering?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To make a input box like word is too difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a built-in solution, so I fixed the issue (more of a workaround really, but so far it's working fine) by calling `BeginUndoGroup` from the `KeyDown` event handler, and calling `EndUndoGroup` in the `TextChanged` handler.

I'm also disabling/enabling the `TextChanged` handler before and after applying the syntax highlight, or that handler would be executed while I'm applying the text formatting.

Also, it seems it's not important to call `Begin`/`EndUndoGroup` in perfect pairs, as calling either one of them in the wrong situation (for example, calling `EndUndoGroup` when there isn't a new open group, or `BeginUndoGroup` two times in a row) simply does nothing, so that's one less thing to worry about.